# My MongoDb on Windows 2008R2 suddenly don't allow writes from C# code

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have had a MongoDb 3.2 on Windows 2008R2 that I installed on my local home server. It is used for a movie database. It has worked fine for years. Now it suddenly stops working. When I debug from my VS2017 using C# code I find that all writes just freeze. They have never had problems before.

```
_movies.ReplaceOneAsync(x => x._id == movie._id, movie, new UpdateOptions { IsUpsert = true }).Wait();
```

When I do the same calling Mongo database on my local computer it works fine. I tried to upgrade Mongo on server to use latest 3.4.6 there too but it made no difference. Then I deleted database and recreated content from backup. Still no success.

On server I can easily connect to Mongo database with Studio 3T. Everything looks fine. With Studio 3T I can also connect from my developer machine.

Windows server machine has also stopped allowing remote access. Can that be related? I have NOT changed any configurations.

All suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Are you able to write to the database from your VS dev machine using either the Mongo shell or Studio 3t? Are you maybe mixing calls to `.Wait()` and `await`, which can cause problems? Maybe try to `await` rather than `Wait` and see if that helps. Maybe also try a completely new and trivial test project that just tries to write to your database and see if that works.

Comment: Thanks Kdawg. From Dev machine I can call database from Studio 3T. I have exchanged all waits with await but no difference. Note that the code works fine when calling local Mongo database. After too much frustration I gave up and moved the whole database to the cloud. Now everything works. I still suspect a Windows Update made some change to my 2008R2 but I can't prove it ...